# Does Gideon have cameras to see what goes on in DC's Legends of Tomorrow?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow, gideon

In Season 3 Episode 7 of Legends of Tomorrow somebody steals Jefferson Jackson's pecan pie from the fridge, and he asked Gideon who on the ship the thief was. This got me thinking and remembering that this is not the first time Gideon has been asked questions about who did stuff, and obviously the only way for Gideon to know these things is if they had cameras. Is Gideon perhaps linked to the security cameras they have on the Waverider, or does she have special cameras designed specifically for her?

Comment: Gideon is the AI so controls all of the electronic stuff on the ship

Comment: She can "see" *the dreams* of her crew -- actual cameras, while there, are child's play to her.

Comment: I forgot that she was able to see the minds of the crew members.

Comment: Gideon can detect *Time Anomalies* across entire spacetime and you think that she needs camera to see crew of waverider?

Comment: @SatelliteofSin Time Anomalies can be found with her AI calculations, and to see you would need some form of camera. What about her calculations means she can magically see without cameras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's reasonable to assume that Gideon, the AI of the ship, has access to the electronics on the ship. And since the Waverider was designed for 1 person but has 36 compartments, a lot of these compartments were intended to hold people/anomalies against their will and therefore would require monitoring.

Also, Gideon has a Neural Monitor that lets her monitor the crew's dreams (S1E10) and also put Zari into a simulated Groundhog day (S3E11). I think she's capable of monitoring the crew, with or without the cameras.